# Getting all group names in signalr

Tags: c#, signalr

ok so I have this code

```
var c = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SomeHubClass>().Clients;
```

now from this the Clients returns an IHubConext that has IHubConnectionContext that has an IGroupManager Groups. now is there anyway to get all the group names from this? Is this even possible with the signalR interface or do I have to track all the groups for each hub myself?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SignalR does not have an exposed API for managing groups as a whole, iterating over groups, or even obtaining a summary list of groups.  You can only add or remove groups.  If you want to persist a list of group names, perhaps use a singleton pattern for your SomeHubClass.  Persist a `List<string>` of group names in the singleton that you can easily access, or even a `Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>` to map both the name and the hashset of connection ids, though that is probably overkill in this instance.

See http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub for implementing a singleton of your hub.

Comment: sounds good so each hub class would have to have it's own data structure for keeping track of each group. I figured this but I just needed to be sure.

Answer (score 7):

You CAN ACTUALLY GET all group names using reflection (because all fields that we need are private) like I did, also here is how I dug it:
IGroupManager -> _lifetimeManager -> _groups -> _groups

```
IGroupManager groupManager = signalRHubContext.Groups;

object lifetimeManager = groupManager.GetType().GetRuntimeFields()
    .Single(fi => fi.Name == "_lifetimeManager")
    .GetValue(groupManager);

object groupsObject = lifetimeManager.GetType().GetRuntimeFields()
    .Single(fi => fi.Name == "_groups")
    .GetValue(lifetimeManager);

IDictionary groupsDictionary = groupsObject.GetType().GetRuntimeFields()
    .Single(fi => fi.Name == "_groups")
    .GetValue(groupsObject) as IDictionary;

List<string> groupNames = groupsDictionary.Keys.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

Comment: While this is a solution, I don't think it's a great idea, the fields are private for a reason. Private fields can be changed at any time and could cause unforeseen bugs