# SignalR monitoring connectionIds/Users in a Group

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a pretty simple piece of code as follows to register a user to a Group.

```
 public async Task JoinRoom(string roomName)
    {
        await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
        Clients.Group(roomName).NewPlayer(Context.User.Identity.Name);
    }
```

Is it now possible to access which users are in which group?

Do I need to use `ConcurrentDictionary` or a database to handle such a task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer: [Getting all group names in signalr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351493/getting-all-group-names-in-signalr#19351677)

I am afraid you have to manage this info by your own.