# SignalR get groups user is in

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm  making a 1-to-1 chat application and I'm using groups for that.

You join a group with `Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, roomName)`.

And whenever a message is sent, I want to call

```
Clients.Group(roomName).addMessage(username, text);
```

But for that I need a `roomName` variable. How do I retrieve the rooms an user joined?

Comment: have you got any solution or still you are finding ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no specific api to manage groups, you need to persist this information your self.

[There is a related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351493/getting-all-group-names-in-signalr)

For more complete information, you can see the Signalr topic

[Working with Groups in SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups)

> Groups in SignalR provide a method for broadcasting messages to
>   specified subsets of connected clients. A group can have any number of
>   clients, and a client can be a member of any number of groups. You
>   don't have to explicitly create groups. In effect, a group is
>   automatically created the first time you specify its name in a call to
>   Groups.Add, and it is deleted when you remove the last connection from
>   membership in it. For an introduction to using groups, see [How to
>   manage group membership from the Hub class in the Hubs API](http://How%20to%20manage%20group%20membership%20from%20the%20Hub%20class) - Server
>   Guide.

**How to manage group membership from the Hub class**

> Groups in SignalR provide a method for broadcasting messages to
>   specified subsets of connected clients. A group can have any number of
>   clients, and a client can be a member of any number of groups.
>
> To manage group membership, use the Add and Remove methods provided by
>   the Groups property of the Hub class.

**Moreover**

> SignalR tracks connections, not users, so if you want a user to be in
>   the same group every time the user establishes a connection, you have
>   to call Groups.Add every time the user establishes a new connection.

In short you have to do it your self. there is an example in the [Working with Groups in SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups) of how you might persist user and group information with a Database.